# how to start my project in android sdk if I don't have domain

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk, android-sdk-tools

In the android studio it was asked to provide our website (domain) in order to continue but what I can do If I don't have domain or website of my own.

Comment: please make it clear what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Make one up, it doesn't matter. The only thing which is important is that you don't use one that another app in play-store already uses.

Answer (score 0):

Leave that field Blank, It Should work as its working for me, 
Still Facing Problem then Update your Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The company domain name is used to uniquely identify your app. Thus, even if two different companies create Android apps with the same name, you can still see which is which because their company domain names will be different. If you have a company, type in the company's domain name in reverse (e.g. com.xxx).

If you have no company, you can just choose a fictive company domain name. To make this first app it doesn't matter so much. Only if you plan to release it to Google Play, then the company domain name matters.

Comment: It would be nice to add references if you copy and paste from somewhere.http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/your-first-android-app.html